# PDF to Image Conversion using Ghostscript

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript

I'm looking to convert a PDF file to an image file, i have previously used GhostScript for this and it worked well. For some reason it has stopped converting and now throws errors that I'm not too sure how to solve.

```
     using (Process p = new Process())
     {
         p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
         p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
         p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
         p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
         p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
         p.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/app/ghostscript/gswin64.exe");
         p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-sDEVICE=tiff12nc -s -dBATCH -r200 -dNOPAUSE  -sOutputFile=" + Server.MapPath("~/temp/temp_" + guid + "/output.tiff") + " " + Server.MapPath("~/temp/temp_" + guid + "/temp.pdf");
         p.Start();
         p.WaitForExit(10000);
      }
```

Once the p.Start() line is reached it throws 2 GhostScript errors;

1. Can't load Ghostscript DLL
2. Can't load DLL, LoadLibrary error code 126

Has anyone had this issue before and managed to get around it?

Comment: You're simply starting an application, not loading any DLL. Have you tried running this specific command-line from a shell? From the *same folder* where you try to execute that code? It's quite likely that `~/app/ghostscript` ins't on the path so the executable can't find the libraries it needs. All you need to do is set the `WorkingDirectory` property to `~/app/ghostscript`

Comment: On the other hand, executing other processes from inside a web application is a *very* bad idea - it doesn't scale at all and introduces serious vulnerabilities. The service account has to be given access to extra folders and a hacker could easily inject script code that runs using the service account's increased permissions. Someone could take advantage of any Ghostscript vulnerabilities to run code using a malicious PDF document

Comment: The error means the Ghostscript executbale can't find its DLL, which it requires. Ghostscript (the executable) uses an entry in the Registry to try and find the Ghostscript DLL. If the Registry, or the entry, has been corrupted then I believe Windows will search the path. The first thing I would suggest is that you check the Ghostscript installation directory to see if the DLL has been deleted. Then you can either check the Registry manually; HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GPL GhostScript\x.xx and then look for the GS_DLL key and check its value, or you could just re-install Ghostscript.

Comment: Thank you, the issue with the DLL is now resolved

Answer (score 0):

BTW, the bare '-s' in the arguments is probably left over from something else that was previously there. I'm sort of surprised that it doesn't throw an error, but you got lucky -- all it does it put a zero length string with and empty name into systemdict.
This can be seen by then executing the PS sequence: systemdict () cvn get
which returns a 0 length object of stringtype.
Without the bare -s argument that sequence throws: Error: /undefined in --get--